# Change current Index input dynamic jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, each

I want change current Idx(index) in input name, after remove inputs.

At the beginning of the input names of the is as:

row 1 : `airline[0] flight_time[0] flight_number[0]` 
row 2 : `dOfv[]` 
row 3 : `airline[2] flight_time[2] flight_number[2]`

now, after remove row 2, i want change input name in other rows like this:

row 1 : `airline[0] flight_time[0] flight_number[0]` 
row 3 : `airline[1] flight_time[1] flight_number[1]`

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/5nykq0e6/

what do i do?

Html:

```
<div class="one">
    1.<input name="airline[0]">
        <input name="flight_time[0]">
            <input name="flight_number[0]">
    <a href="" class="remove_input">X</a>
</div>
<div class="one">
    2.<textarea name="dOfv[]"></textarea>
    <a href="" class="remove_input">X</a>
</div>
<div class="one">
    3.<input name="airline[2]">
        <input name="flight_time[2]">
            <input name="flight_number[2]">
    <a href="" class="remove_input">X</a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.remove_input', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('div.one').remove();

    $('.one').each(function(i, el) {
        //return parseInt($.trim(text)) - 1;
        var text = $(el).text();
        var currentIdx = parseInt(str.match(/\d+/)[0], 10);
        $(el).text('name', str.replace(currentIdx, i));
    })

})
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code here - not just a link to JSFiddle.

Comment: why not just leave the indexes out ? `airline[]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str` was never defined replace by your text :

```
$(el).text('name', text.replace(currentIdx, i));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5nykq0e6/1/